# Verificar código

Tags: java, revisión-de-código, poo

El problema que tengo yo creo que es de organización. Lo que pasa es que me imprime una palabra, pero el juego pone otra diferente

Este es el paquete models

```
package models;
import java.util.Random;
import models.EnumWords;

public class Hangman    {
    //CONSTANTS
    public static EnumWords word;
    //Attributes
    //1st Constructor
    public Hangman()    {
        setWord(EnumWords.NOTEXT);
    }
    //2nd Constructor
    public Hangman(EnumWords word)  {
        setWord(word);
    }
    public EnumWords wordsSelect()  {
        Random wordRandom = new Random();
        int wordOfGame = 1 + wordRandom.nextInt(16);
        switch(wordOfGame){
        case 1 : word = EnumWords.ALGORITMO; break; 
        case 2 : word = EnumWords.BOYACÁ; break;
        case 3 : word = EnumWords.CLASE; break; 
        case 4 : word = EnumWords.COMPUTADOR; break;
        case 5 : word = EnumWords.DIFÍCIL; break; 
        case 6 : word = EnumWords.GUERRA; break;
        case 7 : word = EnumWords.INTERNET; break; 
        case 8 : word = EnumWords.JAVA; break;
        case 9 : word = EnumWords.LEER; break; 
        case 10 : word = EnumWords.NADA; break;
        case 11 : word = EnumWords.PROGRAMACIÓN; break; 
        case 12 : word = EnumWords.SANGRE; break;
        case 13 : word = EnumWords.TUNJA; break; 
        case 14 : word = EnumWords.INGENIERIA; break;
        case 15 : word = EnumWords.UPTC; break;
        case 16 : word = EnumWords.SISTEMAS; break; 
        }
        return word;
    }
    public String WordLine(String word){
        EnumWords text = wordsSelect();
        word = text.toString();
        String auxWord = word;
        int large = word.length()*2;
        String change = "_ ";
        while(change.length()< large){
            change += "_ ";
        }
        auxWord = change;   
    return auxWord;

}
    //Setter

    public void setWord(EnumWords word) {
        this.word = word;
    }
    //Getter
    public EnumWords getWord()  {
        return word;
    }
}
```

paquete vista

```
package views;
import models.Hangman;
import models.EnumWords;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class HangmanForm{
    private static Scanner readerString = new Scanner (System.in);

    public static Hangman build(){
        System.out.println("+------------------------------------------+");
        System.out.println("|              EL AHORCADO                 |");
        System.out.println("+------------------------------------------+");
        System.out.println("+------------------------------------------+");
        Hangman object1 = new Hangman();
        EnumWords text = object1.wordsSelect();
        String sentence = text.toString();
        String auxWord = object1.WordLine(sentence);
        System.out.println(sentence);
        System.out.println(auxWord);
        int lives = 7;
        int countWin = 0;
        while (lives != 0) {
            System.out.print("Ingrese una letra:");
            String letter = readerString.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            char charLetter = letter.charAt(0);
            for (int x = 0; x < sentence.length(); x++) {
                if (sentence.toUpperCase().charAt(x) == charLetter) {
                    countWin++;
                    auxWord = cambiarString(auxWord,charLetter,x*2);
                    System.out.println("Puntos Buenos :" + countWin);
                    System.out.println(auxWord);
                }
                if (sentence.toUpperCase().charAt(x) != charLetter) {
                    lives--;
                    break;
                }
            }
            print(lives);
            }
        if(lives == 0)
        System.out.println("La palabra era: " + sentence);
        Hangman hang = new Hangman();
        System.out.println("___________________________________________");
        System.out.println("                         Realizado por YG");
        return hang;
    }


    public static void print(int lives){
            if(lives == 6){
                System.out.println("  ---------------------¬");
                System.out.println(" |                     |");
                System.out.println(" |                     |");
                System.out.println(" |                  ");
                System.out.println(" |                ");
                System.out.println(" |                 ");
                System.out.println(" |                  ");
                System.out.println(" |                        ");
                System.out.println(" |                       ");
                System.out.println(" |                         ");
                System.out.println(" |                          ");
                System.out.println(" |                        ");
                System.out.println(" |                        ");
                System.out.println(" |                           ");
                System.out.println(" |                           ");
                System.out.println(" ______________");
                }
            else if(lives == 5){
                System.out.println("  ---------------------¬");
                System.out.println(" |                     |");
                System.out.println(" |                     |");
                System.out.println(" |                  -------");
                System.out.println(" |                 | -  -  |");
                System.out.println(" |                 |   o   |");
                System.out.println(" |                  -------");
                System.out.println(" |                        ");
                System.out.println(" |                       ");
                System.out.println(" |                         ");
                System.out.println(" |                          ");
                System.out.println(" |                        ");
                System.out.println(" |                        ");
                System.out.println(" |                           ");
                System.out.println(" |                           ");
                System.out.println(" ______________");
            }
            else if(lives == 4){
                System.out.println("  ---------------------¬");
                System.out.println(" |                     |");
                System.out.println(" |                     |");
                System.out.println(" |                  -------");
                System.out.println(" |                 | -  -  |");
                System.out.println(" |                 |   o   |");
                System.out.println(" |                  -------");
                System.out.println(" |                     |   ");
                System.out.println(" |                     |  ");
                System.out.println(" |                     |    ");
                System.out.println(" |                     |     ");
                System.out.println(" |                     |   ");
                System.out.println(" |                        ");
                System.out.println(" |                           ");
                System.out.println(" |                           ");
                System.out.println(" ______________");
            }
            else if(lives == 3){
                System.out.println("  ---------------------¬");
                System.out.println(" |                     |");
                System.out.println(" |                     |");
                System.out.println(" |                  -------");
                System.out.println(" |                 | -  -  |");
                System.out.println(" |                 |   o   |");
                System.out.println(" |                  -------");
                System.out.println(" |                     |   ");
                System.out.println(" |                   / |  ");
                System.out.println(" |                  /  |    ");
                System.out.println(" |                 /   |      ");
                System.out.println(" |                     |   ");
                System.out.println(" |                        ");
                System.out.println(" |                           ");
                System.out.println(" |                           ");
                System.out.println(" ______________");
            }
            else if(lives == 2){
                System.out.println("  ---------------------¬");
                System.out.println(" |                     |");
                System.out.println(" |                     |");
                System.out.println(" |                  -------");
                System.out.println(" |                 | -  -  |");
                System.out.println(" |                 |   o   |");
                System.out.println(" |                  -------");
                System.out.println(" |                     |   ");
                System.out.println(" |                   / | \\ ");
                System.out.println(" |                  /  |   \\ ");
                System.out.println(" |                 /   |     \\ ");
                System.out.println(" |                     |   ");
                System.out.println(" |                        ");
                System.out.println(" |                           ");
                System.out.println(" |                           ");
                System.out.println(" ______________");
            } 
           else if(lives == 1){
                System.out.println("  ---------------------¬");
                System.out.println(" |                     |");
                System.out.println(" |                     |");
                System.out.println(" |                  -------");
                System.out.println(" |                 | -  -  |");
                System.out.println(" |                 |   o   |");
                System.out.println(" |                  -------");
                System.out.println(" |                     |   ");
                System.out.println(" |                   / | \\ ");
                System.out.println(" |                  /  |   \\ ");
                System.out.println(" |                 /   |     \\ ");
                System.out.println(" |                     |   ");
                System.out.println(" |                    /   ");
                System.out.println(" |                   /       ");
                System.out.println(" |                  /        ");
                System.out.println(" ______________");
           }
           else if(lives == 0){
               System.out.println(" ---------------------");
                System.out.println(" |                     |");
                System.out.println(" |                     |");
                System.out.println(" |                  -------");
                System.out.println(" |                 | X  X  |");
                System.out.println(" |                 |   o   |");
                System.out.println(" |                  -------");
                System.out.println(" |                     |   ");
                System.out.println(" |                   / | \\ ");
                System.out.println(" |                  /  |   \\ ");
                System.out.println(" |                 /   |     \\ ");
                System.out.println(" |                     |   ");
                System.out.println(" |                    / \\");
                System.out.println(" |                   /   \\  ");
                System.out.println(" |                  /     \\ ");
                 System.out.println(" ______________");
                System.out.println("GAME OVER");
        }
    }
    public static String cambiarString(String sentence,char newChar,int index) {
        char[] sequence = sentence.toCharArray();
        sequence[index] = newChar;
        return new String(sequence);
    }
}
```

Me aparece un problema en el paquete vista, supongo que es al importar

Comment: Hola Yeferson, bienvenido a SOes, te sugiero leer http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask como recién estás en el sitio, te será de utilidad, por cierto podrías decirnos: Cuál es la pregunta?